# Javascript if (x==y==z):

Tags: javascript, if-statement, equals-operator

I've got 3 random numbers (in this specific case between 1 and 7 but it doesn't really matter).
I want to check whether I got "three of a kind" by using

```
if (x==y==z) {
code
}
```

The problem is that when `x==y` and `z==1` `x==y==z` will return true. How do I check whether x, y and z actually got the SAME value?

Example: `5==5==1` will return true, how do I check for `5==5==5` specifically? (Excluding `5==5==1`)

Comment: This is not python, you cannot chain conditionals...

Comment: Duplicate is of another language, but the principle applies. If someone can find a more suitable duplicate, feel free to adjust.

Answer (score 5):

By doing a proper comparison:

```
x === y && y === z
// due to transitivity, if the above expression is true, x === z must be true as well
```

---

`x==y==z` is actually evaluated as

```
(x == y) == z
```

i.e. you are either comparing `true == z` or `false == z` which I think is not what you want. In addition, it does type conversion. To give you an extreme example:

```
[1,2,4] == 42 == "\n" // true
```

> The problem is that when `x==y` and `z==1`, `x==y==z` will return true.

Yes, because `x == y` will be `true`, so you compare `true == 1`. `true` will be converted to the number `1` and `1 == 1` is `true`.

Comment: And just to cover all bases: there is no need to check `x === z` because they both `=== y`.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with separate `&&` operations

```
if(x == y && x == z){
   //all are equal
}
```